# How can I securely attach a sacrificial top to my radial arm saw table?

Tags: radial-arm-saw

I have just built a table for my RAS using two pieces of 1/2" MDF glued together. I plan on adding a sacrificial top to this using 1/4" PLY. I am wondering what the best method for adhering this to the MDF would be if my plan is to replace it when it gets worn out.[image: RAS with Table, PLY not attached.]

I have seen others use finishing nails to hold it in place. I am just concerned this will put many holes in my MDF, and not be the most secure.

Comment: I received a RAS a few years ago, and the previous owner had used finishing nails to attach the top. This was very insecure, and I ended up ripping it off.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Welcome to stackexchange. I'm not exactly sure I understand your question, but I think I do. Have you considered attaching it with machine screws? Maybe you can attach/detach with wing nuts or star knobs?

I've actually done something similar with my crosscut sled on my table saw. I have a piece of 1/4 in ply in the center where it meets the kurf. I switch it out when the blade deflects and no longer is a zero clearance slot. As long as the machine screws are far enough from the blade, you only have to cut a few holes once in the MDF (and of course, matching holes in the 1/4 ply) and you don't have to cut any more holes.

Good luck!

**Edit**: Based on your comments, it sounds like you need a t-nut in the mdf side and a machine screw on the plywood side (countersunk in). Then you won't have any hardware getting in the way.

Comment: That is what I was going to recommend!

Comment: Great minds think alike, @bowlturner!

Comment: I have used machine screws to attach the MDF to the frame of the RAS. I should maybe note I am trying to keep this top surface as clean as possible. I may have to go this route though.

Comment: It's hard to tell from the picture, but can you countersink the heads at the top and do a star knob (or wing nut) from the bottom?

Comment: One more thought....if you don't have room on the bottom, you could do a t-nut on the mdf and a machine screw countersunk from the top. You'll have to have a screw driver to tighten the screw into the t-nut, but you won't be doing that very often so it shouldn't be too bad.

Comment: I didn't consider a t-nut, that may be a good solution!